# @client.event() TypeError: Client.event() missing 1 required positional argument: 'coro'

Tags: python, discord.py

I am making a discord music bot for my server and i am not an expert in python but i have coded a bot or 2 and this is the first time i ever had this problem
when i try to run this code i get this error
@client.event()
TypeError: Client.event() missing 1 required positional argument: 'coro'

any help is appreciated

```
import discord
import os
import asyncio
import youtube_dl


client = discord.Client(intents = discord.Intents.all())

voice_clients = {}

yt_dl_opts = {'format': 'bestaudio/best'}
ytdl = youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(yt_dl_opts)

ffmpeg_options = {'options': "-vn"}

#this says if the bot is logged in or not 

@client.event()
async def on_ready():
  print (f"bot logged in as {client.user}")



@client.event
async def on_message(msg):
  
  if msg.content.startswith("$play"):
    try:
              
      url = msg.content.split()[1]

      voice_client = await msg.author.voice.channel.connect()
      voice_clients[voice_client.guild.id]= voice_client

      loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
      data = await loop.run_in_executor(None, lambda: ytdl.extract_info(url, download = False))

      song = data['url']
      player = discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(song, **ffmpeg_options)

      voice_client.play(player)


    except Exception as err:
        print (err)



client.run("TOKEN")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a `@client.event()` before your `on_ready` function, should just be `@client.event` like you have done on the `on_message` event. Need to remove the parentheses for it to be valid. [`event`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Client.event) docs here.

```py
@client.event
async def on_ready():
  print (f"bot logged in as {client.user}")
```